# Script loaded, however unable to call any of its functions

Tags: javascript, html

I have a generic javascript function which should toggle a class on and off, however I cannot call the funtion.

I can see the function getting loaded on the network tab of inspect element, I can even read my script, but even in the console tab, I cannot call my function. I have done this many times before however cannot figure this one out.

My script is as follows:

```js
function updateTags(tagSelected){
 if(document.getElementById(tagSelected).classList.contains("selected")){
  document.getElementById(tagSelected).classList.remove("selected");
 } else{
  document.getElementById(tagSelected).classList.add("selected");
 }
}
```

```css
button{
background-color:green;
}
.selected{
background-color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="tag-button" onclick="updateTags('SUP')" id="SUP">SUP</button><br>
```

The only thing to note is that the buttons that call the script are loaded by a php script seperate to the main page. They are loaded in using a require, and all appear correctly. If I copy and paste the function into the console tab, it becomes usable, so I just cannot understand what is happening!

Below are screenshots of my script being loaded, and the error I am getting.
[image: Script being loaded]
[image: Error message]

Comment: How is the script loaded?  It's possible to download the file without making it available, so need to see that code also

Comment: @Ben Robinson sorry - it was a stupid mistake on my part, I answered below but was only due to a syntax error causing me grief. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, just spent the last 2 hours trying to figure this out. Turns out, I was missing a plus sign in the second function in my script. Fixed now, and works perfectly, thanks!